# how can I assign value into 2-D array by using their address?

Tags: c++

I'm going to rewrite a program that is using pointer & dynamic array

but for 2-D array part, here are some question

This is the original code:

```
  for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++)
  {
     sorted[index][0] = sum[index];
     sorted[index][1] = index+1;
 }
```

And I rewrite it like this :

```
for (int index = 0; index < 12; index++)
{
    *(*sorted+index) = *(sum+index);
    *((*sorted+index)+1) = index + 1;
}
```

I have tried and the problem is occur in first part of the assign
`*(*sorted+index)` and `*((*sorted+index)+1)`

what is the problem going on? There are no error code, the descrition is just:

> Exception thrown at 0x00F47379 in ass2 Q3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0xCE13E05C. Unhandled exception at
>   0x00F47379 in ass2 Q3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0xCE13E05C.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in these 2 lines:

```
*(*sorted+index) = *(sum+index);
*((*sorted+index)+1) = index + 1;
```

You need to move the `sorted` pointer by `index` offset, and to do so you should write `(sorted + index)` now you can get the value stored in this address by `*(sorted + index)` then get the first element by `*(*(sorted + index))`. The same thing must be applied to the second line too, so those 2 lines should be:

```
*(*(sorted+index)) = *(sum+index);
*(*(sorted+index)+1) = index + 1;
```

I suggest that you read more about pointer arithmetic.